# Is there a way to quickly find a views.py file for a specific module using pydev in eclipse?

Tags: django, eclipse, pydev

I'm using pydev and eclipse, while working on a django project that has about 30 modules. I usually use CTRL+SHIFT+R to open a file in eclipse. But when I'm looking for a views.py file and type in 'views', I get 30 files which are all named views.py. The module name is shown behind the filename, but with 30 files it still takes me a while to find the right one. When I type in the module name too, all files disappear.

So my question: Is there a way to quickly acces a views.py file (or models.py file for that matter) of a specific module in eclipse, using pydev?

Comment: Are you using navigator? You can also create working set for PyDev File search within a specific module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent versions of PyDev, modules also appear in Ctrl+Shift+T.

There, say you have the views.py in a structure my_project.my_app.views.py, you could put in your search 'm.m.views' and it should be able to point you to the views.py in the my_project.my_app.

Note that if you know a function inside views.py you can type that function directly.